# What limits are possible when running Google's Javascript Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, limits

I'm aware of the usage limits when using Google's free, publicly available Javascript Maps API. Currently 25,000 daily Maps loads are your limit.

It seems though that also limits on the delivering servers are somehow in place.

I'm running a website on https://zugspitze360.com that is heavily using the API to display photo spheres (panorama photos) and it seems that for certain users or times the loading of imagery is resulting in 403 HTTP responses on Google servers.

Can't find any errors in the Google Developer Console though. And also can't find any information on usage limits in terms of imagery loads, etc

Comment: Are you using the geocoding? There is also a limitation of queries per second. Perhaps this is the reason why?

Comment: No, no geocoding. Primarily the error occurred while loading 360 Street View imagery.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages), check if the API key included in the request is valid then try to clear your cache. I have found this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302757/google-maps-api-v3-error-403-forbidden-access-for-too-many-pageviews) which suggested to make sure that you aren't accidentally DOSing them with http requests to avoid 403 error. It will invariably burn through your limit, and potentially place your IP on a blacklist. Also check if you are not caching (or storing locally) the google maps js script. Google don't allow that.

Comment: What is my limit? When the error occurred we were well under the Maps loads limit of 25,000 loads/day. I would say what happened is what you described, we were somehow blacklisted, at least partially. Don't know what to do though, it's in the nature of photospheres that multiple requests are made. Also we don't cache the Maps API.